# How kafka manager get the Consumer Instance Owner?

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

How [kafka manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) to get consumer instance owner? `Zookeeper` or `jmx mbean`?

In new kafka version, only use `ConsumerGroupCommand.main` to get the owner info?

kafka:0.10.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Since Kafka 0.9 [the information is stored at broker](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/). For each group, one of the brokers is selected as the group coordinator. Assigned consumer might change after rebalancing.

Search for `ConsumerPartitionOwnershipInfo` in [the design docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Detailed+Consumer+Coordinator+Design#KafkaDetailedConsumerCoordinatorDesign-12.1kafka.api).